# Rspec cannot find custom module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I try to test devise user authentication, the problem I've done everything according to samples, however the code still doesn't work.

spec/support/devise/devise_support.rb

```
module ValidUserRequestHelper
    def sign_in_as_a_valid_user
        @user ||= Fabricate(:simple_user)
        post_via_redirect user_session_path, 'user[email]' => @user.email, 'user[password]' => @user.password
    end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include ValidUserRequestHelper, :type => :request
end
```

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
```

However when I run test, it fails on the calling to `sign_in_as_a_valid_user'

```
undefined local variable or method `sign_in_as_a_valid_user' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0xc57a0c4>
```

I don't have idea how to debug this.

The test code is

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
        sign_in_as_a_valid_user
  end

...
```

Comment: Please share your test code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you write this in your rspec configuration

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ValidUserRequestHelper, :type => :request
end
```

you tell rspec to only include this helper for request spec. those are typically located in `spec/request`. deriving from the example of your spec that has `describe User` in it, i assume that you are writing a model spec, typically located in `spec/model`. so when running the spec, rspec won't include it for that spec!

if you just remove the `:type => :request` it will get included everywhere. keep in mind, that there is usually a good reason for this kind of restrictions. for example a helper that only works with a fake browser, like it is done in request specs.

Comment: not really, but you can have a look at living examples here: https://github.com/phoet/on_ruby